# Construct a string without allocation

Tags: c++, string

Considering we have a struct with char * member, if we want to request the content of this member, we normally do

```
char const * get_member() { return object.member; }
```

By this, we only return a pointer, without any allocation.

If now we want to return a string; is it possible to let the string just use that pointer, instead of copying the content and construct a new string object?

```
string const & get_member() { return object.member; }
```

will this code above will do a memory allocation. what like of extra work will this method do compare to the `char const *` one?

Comment: Can you not just `const string * get_member()`?

Comment: will this allocate memory for the string?

Comment: Or even `const std::string& get_member()`.

Comment: have your member be an std::string. Return const std::string&

Comment: `std::string_view` is an option, too. It's compatible with the `char*` member, but, as with the current code, places the burden of managing relative lifetimes on the caller. It's considerably harder to accidentally keep a reference instead of a copy if calling one that returns `const string&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. `std::string` always allocates its own memory and cannot take ownership of a pre-existing buffer.

You can either return a copy of the pointer, or you can use a `std::string` member in the first place, and return a reference to it. Or, alternatively return `std::string_view` which can be used with either `char*` or a `std::string` member. String view is only available since C++17 but it also exists in standard library extensions some for earlier compilers and there also exists non-standard implementations.

> The struct is from some C code based library, just want to wrap with C++, at the mean time, do not kill any performance.

Then it seems that returning a `std::string` would not be an appropriate design.